# Autoencoder with single hidden layer = input

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, autoencoder

I'm exploring the autoencoders for tabular data compression and now want to perform "sanity check". Shouldn't the AE with single linear layer with the same number of neurons as the input columns dimension be perfect?

Unfortunately it doesn't work as expected, error drops very slow with big fluctuations. Probably I do something wrong?

First of all I scaled data with RobustScaler (due to outliers). Should I also apply binning maybe?
Then this is my code of AE and training loop:

```
data_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset = train,
                                          batch_size = 1024,
                                          shuffle = True)

class Autoencoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, dim = 42):
        super().__init__()
        self.encoder = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(dim, dim),
        )
        
        self.decoder = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(dim, dim),
        )
        
    
    def forward(self, x):
        encoded = self.encoder(x)
        decoded = self.decoder(encoded)
        return encoded, decoded

model = Autoencoder()
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.AdamW(model.parameters(), lr = 1e-3, weight_decay = 1e-5)

num_epochs = 8000
outputs = []
losses = []

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for batch_idx, data in enumerate(data_loader):
        data = data.reshape(-1, dim).to(torch.float32)
        encoded_data, reconstructed_data = model(data)
        loss = criterion(reconstructed_data, data)
        
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        
        losses.append(loss)
    
    print(f'Epoch:{epoch + 1}, Loss:{loss.item(): .4f}')
    outputs.append((epoch, data, reconstructed_data))
```

On the 5710th epochs MSE is still huge:

Epoch:5712, Loss: 274213.4062
Epoch:5713, Loss: 86394.6094
Epoch:5714, Loss: 273.6416
Epoch:5715, Loss: 10154.5342
Epoch:5716, Loss: 3190.9241
Epoch:5717, Loss: 139083.5625
Epoch:5718, Loss: 2009176.5000
Epoch:5719, Loss: 44186.4062
Epoch:5720, Loss: 765.0375
Epoch:5721, Loss: 8315.2373
Epoch:5722, Loss: 4472.9312
Epoch:5723, Loss: 20465.9277
Epoch:5724, Loss: 9247.8584
Epoch:5725, Loss: 141.1344
Epoch:5726, Loss: 1017.8133

Am I doing everything right? Probably I need to wait more epochs?

Thanks a lot.